# What does ‘?’ stand for in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, named-parameters

I have this SQL by a programmer:

```
$sql = "  
   INSERT INTO  
    `{$database}`.`table`  
   (  
    `my_id`,  
    `xType`,  
    `subType`,  
    `recordID`,  
    `textarea`  
   )  
   VALUES  
   (  
    {$my_id},  
    ?xType,  
    ?subType,  
    {$recordID},  
    ?areaText  
   ) ";
```

My question is why is he using `?` before values? How do I see what values are coming in? I did `echo` and it shows `?xType` as `?xType`. No values. What does ? stand for in SQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like a [named parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874353/using-named-parameters-with-mysql-net-provider) to me.

Comment: +1 But that seems to be specific to the .NET provider.  I don't know any use for that style of parameter in PHP.

Comment: The syntax `?<var name>` is MySQL specific, not .NET specific.

Comment: The SQL standard would use `:<var name>`, and the chronic lack of use of these things by PHP programmers has been a blight on the good name of programmers for a long time (c.f. SQL injection attacks).

Answer (score 1):

John Weldon is right in this case but i have seen sql like the below where ? means it is a placeholder for a value. The sql is accompanied by parameters equal to the amount of ?'s in the sql. In that case it means pull the value from the parameter and escape it.

```
INSERT INTO  
    `{$database}`.`table`  
   (  
    `my_id`,  
    `xType`,  
    `subType`,  
    `recordID`,  
    `textarea`  
   )  
   VALUES  
   (  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ?,  
    ? 
   ) ";
```

Comment: Those are positional parameters. With named parameters, you (in effect) supply a map from names to values which the query pulls the values out of. That can be a lot clearer, especially in maintenance.

Comment: I know, i was just stating the above in case a user sees positional parameters, expects named parameters and becomes confused.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to be a place holder to be parsed by some sort of parser. Possibly they are under some framework.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another crazy idea -- you're maintaining someone else's code, right?  Does it actually work/run?  If not, did he put in the question mark because he wasn't sure of that parameter or the name of the parameter?  Sometimes I put in stuff that doesn't compile because I know it will force me to go back and figure it out later (so I don't forget).

Comment: -1. John Weldon posted the right answer. 95% of the time when the poster doesnt ask for info like this it is not needed and is noise/useless. I should know, i have lots of experience asking questions and getting answers.

Comment: acidzombie24, I was just trying to help, thanks for being a dick and downvoting me.  Oh, and if you have so much experience asking questions, how come your comment is badly written and doesn't make any sense?  Ask for info - what?  Generally when I have a question I have no idea what the answer is and I'm actually looking for someone to help me.

Anyway, now I'm sure you'll flag me or something.  Go ahead, I deserve it because I'm such a terrible member of the community.  Thanks a lot.